# Subtract elements in first list from the second list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

Let's say I have two lists: `full_links`  & `href_links`

I want to remove values in `href_links` which contain duplicate values from `full_links`

For example:

```
full_links = [ 1,2,3,4,5]
href_links = [ 1,2,7,8,9,3]
```

So, the output should be:

```
comb_list = [7,8,9]
```

My code is:

```
comb_list = list(set(full_links) - set(href_links))
```

But it is not working.

Comment: Since you're using `set`, I take it preserving order within the list isn't important.

Comment: Note that using sets don't work with lists that contain duplicates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To take out/remove `X` from `Y`, you subtract `X` from `Y`: `Y - X`

```
comb_list = list(set(href_links) - set(full_links))
```

You want to remove (elements of) `full_links` from `href_link`,
also called difference:

```
comb_list = list(set(href_links).difference(set(full_links)))
```

---

If you need to save the order,

```
>>> full_links = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> href_links = [1,2,7,8,9,3]
>>> full_set = set(full_links)
>>> [i for i in href_links if i not in full_set]
[7, 8, 9]
```

Also, there is no need to construct 2 sets if you use the `difference` method:

```
>>> list(set(href_links).difference(full_links))
[7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 5):

It should be the other way round

```
>>> full_links = [ 1,2,3,4,5]
>>> href_links = [ 1,2,7,8,9,3]
>>> comb_list = list(set(full_links)  - set(href_links))
>>> comb_list
[4, 5]
>>> comb_list = list(set(href_links)  - set(full_links))
>>> comb_list
[8, 9, 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

Because it's backwards!

```
comb_list = list(set(href_links) - set(full_links))
```